# Get value in parentheses String VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split

I have an string like this:

```
Dim value as string = "hy the number is (30.01)"
```

How i can get this number 30.01 into another variable?
I am thinking to use `split`, How i can use to get this value thanks

Comment: Is the string going to be in the exact same format each time?

Comment: Yes, in a double format Ex: 10.00, 30.01, 5.50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your format is going to be exactly the same, you can try using Split like you mentioned. This can be very fragile if anything changes.

See if this works for you.

```
Dim result As Double
Dim value As String = "hy the number is (30.01)"
Dim subValue() As String = value.Split("(")
subValue(1) = subValue(1).TrimEnd(")")
If Not Double.TryParse(subValue(1), result) Then
    'Error handling code here
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expressions (System.Text.RegularExpressions):

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(value, "\((?<n>\d+\.\d{2})\)")
If m.Success Then
  Dim n As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(m.Groups("n").Value)
End If
```

Comment: I tryed but i get this error: input string is not formatted correctly

Comment: Sorry, it should be decimal, not integer. Edited my answer.